# Mongoose | Reuse query object

Tags: node.js, mongoose

I am trying to compute the `skip` and `limit` with the total number of documents (`count`).
The issue is that the query object returns the `count` value when I try to get the `items`.

Follows an example:

```
const query = MyModel.find().or([AbilityRule1, AbilityRule2, ...]);
const count = await query.countDocuments(); // count = 3
// Some logic to compute the values of `skip` and `limit` with `count`
// const skip = ...
// const limit = ...
const items = await query.skip(skip).limit(limit); // items = 3 instead of [Model, Model, Model]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found myself with a similar question when I was trying to implement pagination. The answer I came up with was to use the `merge` function on the `Query` object.

```
const query = MyModel.find().or([AbilityRule1, AbilityRule2, ...]);

const count = await MyModel.find().merge(query).countDocuments();

const items = await query.skip(skip).limit(limit);
```

**Source:** https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api/query.html#query_Query-merge

Answer (score 1):

`countDocuments()` looks to be a method of *Model*, not *Query*. I guess in the way you're using it here by calling it on an existing query object, you may be just overwriting it.

Why not just:

```
const query = MyModel.find();
const count = await MyModel.countDocuments();
// ...
const items = await query.skip(skip).limit(limit);
```

Comment: countDocuments() seems to be a Query method. Have a look: https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api/query.html#query_Query-countDocuments
Also, I have updated the first instruction to illustrate that I am trying to reuse the query object by several express middlewares.

Comment: Ok, it is both actually. But you see, the link you provide states that the method as called on a query object actually returns 'this' ie the query object it is called on - not a new query object; So it actually modifies the existing query in place. It further states that the method specifies the query it is called on as a countDocuments() query - as opposed to a regular query I guess. This is my understanding just reading from it and from the code you have provided.

Answer (score 1):

Inspired by Mathew's answer:

I am adding this answer because I find it important that the second and third instructions do not depend on `MyModel`, they just depend on the `query` object.

```
const query = MyModel.find().or([AbilityRule1, AbilityRule2, ...]);

const count = await query.model.find().merge(query).countDocuments();
const items = await query.skip(skip).limit(limit);
```